# Java: ClassProblem. Java Novice

Tags: java, class

The problem I am dealing with is that I can't figure out how to make certain values in my class appear which they only return as zeros. I'm a beginner so I don't know much about Java but I have to make 4 classes or 3 types of employees and one class to output their values. But I can't get the values for the commission and union employ to show. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

// Base or Superclass
class Employee
{
    String name;
    String department;
    double pay;
    double hours;
    double money;
    double mission;
    double rate;
    double withheld;
    double moneyc;
    double moneyu;
    double sales;

    public void inputs()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
        name = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter your department: ");
        department = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter your pay per hour: ");
        pay = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter how many hours you worked: ");
        hours = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter your rate of commission(0.00): ");
        rate = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter your withheld amount: ");
        withheld = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter your sales amount: ");
        sales = in.nextDouble();

        money = pay * hours;
    }

    // Accessor Methods
    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getDepartment()
    {
        return this.department;
    }

    public Double getPay()
    {
        return this.pay;
    }

    public Double getHours()
    {
        return this.hours;
    }

    public Double getMoney()
    {
        return this.money;
    }

    public Double getMission()
    {
        return this.mission;
    }

    public Double getRate()
    {
        return this.rate;
    }

    public Double getWithheld()
    {
        return this.withheld;
    }

    public Double getMoneyc()
    {
        return this.moneyc;
    }

    public Double getMoneyu()
    {
        return this.moneyu;
    }

    public Double getSales()
    {
        return this.sales;
    }

    // Mutator Methods
    public void setName(String n)
    {
        name = n;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String d)
    {
        department = d;
    }

    public void setPay(double p)
    {
        pay = p;
    }

    public void setHours(double h)
    {
        hours = h;
    }

    public void setMoney(double m)
    {
        money = m;
    }

    public void setMission(double mi)
    {
        mission = mi;
    }

    public void setRate(double r)
    {
        rate = r;
    }

    public void setWithheld(double w)
    {
        withheld = w;
    }

    public void setMoneyc(double mc)
    {
        moneyc = mc;
    }

    public void setMoneyu(double mu)
    {
        moneyu = mu;
    }

    public void setSales(double s)
    {
        sales = s;
    }
}

class Last extends Employee
{
    public void dinero()
    {
        Employee one = new Employee();

        one.inputs();

        // Union Employee
        UnionEmployee three = new UnionEmployee();
        three.Syndicate();

        // Commission Employee
        Commissioned two = new Commissioned();
        two.sales();

        System.out.println("\n"+ "Name: "+ one.getName());
        System.out.println( "Department: "+ one.getDepartment());
        System.out.println( "Hours: "+ one.getHours());
        System.out.println( "Pay Rate: "+ one.getPay());
        System.out.println("Your money is: "+ one.getMoney());

        // Commissioned Employee
        System.out.println( "\n"+ "Commissioned Employee");
        System.out.println("Your money is: "+ one.getMoneyc());
        System.out.println( "Your commission is: "+ one.getMission());
        System.out.println("Your rate: "+ one.getRate());

        // Union employee
        System.out.println("\n"+"Union Employee");
        System.out.println("Your money is: "+ one.getMoneyu());
        System.out.println( "Your withheld is: "+ one.getWithheld());
    }
}

// Derived or Subclass
class Commissioned extends Employee
{
    public void sales()
    {
        moneyc = hours * pay;
        // Commission
        mission = sales * rate;
    }
}

// Derived or Subclass
class UnionEmployee extends Employee
{
    public void Syndicate()
    {
        if (hours <= 40) {
            moneyu = (hours * pay) - withheld;
        } else  {
            moneyu = (pay * hours * ((hours - 40) * 1.5)) - withheld;
        }
    }
}

public class WeiTry extends Last
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Output
        Last show = new Last();
        show.dinero();
    }
}
```

Comment: And why exactly was `javascript` tagged in this? You do realize `javascript` has nothing to do with `java`.

Comment: Off the JS list it goes.

Comment: Oh sorry like I posted before I'm a Java novice. I have only had a week and a half of actually learning Java.

Comment: can we get a sample input and output?

Comment: Your problem is that everything prints out correctly except the comission (one.getMission()) and what else?

Comment: Sure, just give me a moment and the money made for the union and commission rate.

Answer (score 1):

The only place I see your `Employee`'s fields get set is inside a method called `inputs()`

`one`'s values get populated because you call the `inputs` method on `one` but for your other employee types like your `UnionEmployee three`, `inputs` never called, and their fields never get set.

If you want your other employee's values to get set, it looks like you'll have to call their inputs method.

```
UnionEmployee three = new UnionEmployee();
three.inputs();
three.Syndicate();
```

or you can just copy them over

```
three.setName(one.getName());
```

Comment: Yeah, thats probably why I'm getting zeroes for certain outputs so how would I be able to get to populate variables? Or do I have to just call the method in the other class?

Comment: @RogelioLoop call their `inputs` method

Comment: Here is the output image link: http://i756.photobucket.com/albums/xx207/ChaosOrochi/Java_Problem_zps7c9dc5b4.jpg

Comment: So I would have to add the three.inputs part in my Last class? Sorry if I'm not too knowledgeable.

Comment: @RogelioLoop yes.  You probably want it between `UnionEmployee three = new UnionEmployee();`  and `three.Syndicate();`

Comment: Ok, I think I got it to work but the only thing that bugs me now is that the problem ask for the inputs 3 times. Any suggestions on fixing that?

Comment: you could copy the inputs over to `three` instead of calling `inputs()`  I've included an update to my post

Comment: I just tried doing that but once I do it I only get answers out for everything but for the Union. This is what I did.

Comment: //Union Employee
  
  UnionEmployee three = new UnionEmployee();
  //three.inputs();
  
  three.setName(one.getName());
  
  three.Syndicate();